# Question about joining tables

Tags: sql

What kind of join is actually for the following sql statement?

```
select * 
from table1 tbl1, table2 tbl2 
where tbl1.id = tbl2.id
```

Does it only return result if both id matches?

Answer (score 4):

This is an inner join.

Yes, only records that have matching IDs will be returned.

This is the same as:

```
select * 
from table1 tbl1 
 inner join table2 tbl2 
    on tbl1.id = tbl2.id
```

Personally, I prefer the explicit notation of `INNER JOIN`.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that is ANSI-89 syntax for an inner join.  ANSI-92 defines the [INNER,LEFT, etc...] JOIN keywords.

Comment: I think it's not just an omitted `JOIN` keyword but a completely different syntax: when you are using the `[INNER] JOIN` syntax, you are supposed to specify the condition after the `ON` keyword rather than after `WHERE`

Comment: You're correct, it's ANSI-89 syntax that uses the comma-separated table syntax and where clause for joins.  Editing the post.